# records from yesterday in postrgesql

Tags: postgresql

I have an application in which I've used MySQL. I had a report that stretched records of the last 24 hours. I used the query:

```
WHERE (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= FROM_UNIXTIME(`workorder`.`CREATEDTIME` / 1000))
```

Now I have to use PostgreSQL and do not know how to make a report of the last 24 hours.
Can any of you help?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
WHERE workorder.createdtime > current_date - 1     -- Yesterday and today

WHERE workorder.createdtime > current_timestamp - interval '1 day' -- last 24hr
```

Comment: I have a message: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint > timestamp with time zone

Comment: @Krokodyle This error means your `workorder.createdtime` is a `bigint`. You need to translate it to a proper `date` or `timestamp`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I translated to date. It works! Thanks for your help

Comment: This will take all items after yesterday. Not just today and yesterday.

Answer (score 54):

## `> TIMESTAMP 'yesterday'`

For convenience, Postgres includes a few hard-coded values as [special Date/Time inputs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN6039). They include:

- `yesterday`
- `today`
- `tomorrow`
- `now`

Try `SELECT TIMESTAMP 'now'`.

For example, here is a query.

```sql
SELECT when_row_created_
FROM customer_
WHERE when_row_created_ > TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' 
ORDER BY when_row_created_ DESC
;
```

These commands may not be appropriate to production code, but they certainly are handy in development. Read the docs and do some practice to be sure you understand the behavior of these commands, how the session’s time zone affects them and so on.

Downsides include (a) implicitly ignoring the crucial issue of time zone, and (b) not standard SQL.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are they not appropriate for production code?

Comment: @VillasV For one thing, it ignores the crucial issue of time zone. Implicitly depends on the current time zone of the session. Better to be explicit and specify time zone in your code.

Comment: Another thing worth to mention apart from time zones is (from docs):
"While the input strings `now`, `today`, `tomorrow`, and `yesterday` are fine to use in interactive SQL commands, they can have surprising behavior when the command is saved to be executed later, for example in prepared statements, views, and function definitions. The string can be converted to a specific time value that continues to be used long after it becomes stale. Use one of the SQL functions instead in such contexts. For example, `CURRENT_DATE` + 1 is safer than `'tomorrow'::date.`"

Answer (score 10):

```
where workorder.createdtime >= now() - interval '24 hour'
```

Comment: It's generally better to use the SQL-standard `current_date` keyword rather than `now`.

Comment: Thanks, i m not using postgres very often ufortunately

Answer (score 4):

```
WHERE workorder.createdtime::date = current_date - 1; --from yesterday
```